# Golang: On Linux (centos), the golang application cannot be installed as a service

Tags: linux, centos, golang

I created a Golang program to carry out some functionality. For installation on Linux (centos), I built the application with the appropriate OS and architecture (GOOS=linux, GOARCH=amd64). The application ran successfully when I launched it directly from the linux operating system, however when I tried to install it as a service file, it failed to start the service and threw the following errors.

```
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: goroutine 1 [running]: 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: a360monitoringserver/logger.(*Logger).setLogFile(0xc00001e240) 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: C:/My Work/GoLang/DemoCode/a360monitoring/logger/Logger.go:67 +0x4c5 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: a360monitoringserver/logger.GetLogger.func1() 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: C:/My Work/GoLang/DemoCode/a360monitoring/logger/Logger.go:26 +0x15d 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: sync.(*Once).doSlow(0xc0000761e0?, 0x6c8044?) 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: C:/Program Files/Go/src/sync/once.go:74 +0xc2 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: sync.(*Once).Do(...) 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: C:/Program Files/Go/src/sync/once.go:65 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: a360monitoringserver/logger.GetLogger() 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: C:/My Work/GoLang/DemoCode/a360monitoring/logger/Logger.go:19 +0x31 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: a360monitoringserver/requesthandler.init() 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net a360monitoringserver[27935]: C:/My Work/GoLang/DemoCode/a360monitoring/requesthandler/RequestHandler.go:12 +0x17 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net systemd[1]: a360monitoringserver.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net systemd[1]: Unit a360monitoringserver.service entered failed state. 
May 22 14:30:19 a360monitoring.cloud.automationanywhere.net systemd[1]: a360monitoringserver.service fai
```

Comment: Could you show us the code?

Comment: Hello @Toto as per the policy I can not share the code. but my concern is, I built the code through "GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o myapp" command and the code works fine when I directly launch the application and faces an issue when I installed the application as a service.  Also It shows path from windows machine though I ran the application on linux os

Comment: What's the rest of the error message? You're only showing the last 15 lines, but the useful part is usually near the top of the stacktrace (or even before it).

Comment: on my linux terminal I can see only these many lines is there any way to get full error logs ?

Comment: The issue got resolve, I mentioned the incorrect username in service configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved, I mentioned the incorrect username in a service configuration file. I replace correct name and issue got resolve.

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/tmp
Restart=on-abnormal

User=<username>
Group=<groupname>
```